# tired of vs tired from

Tags: meaning, differences

> He is tired of that work

vs.

> He is tired from that work.

I think the two sentences are almost the same.

If there is any difference, could anyone explain?

Comment: tired of something = fed up with something, bored with something, no longer interested in something; tired from something = (physically or emotionally) tired because of something

Comment: While I would agree with the overall explanations given, "tired from" just sounds like non-standard and klunky English.  Instead, something more like "exhausted by", "worn out from" would sound better.

Answer (score 24):

"Tired of" suggests to me that the person has done enough of that particular work and does not wish to do any more. Perhaps that will change when they've had a break from it, or perhaps they no longer want to do it ever again, but in either case it's an expression of their *attitude* toward the work, not (necessarily) to how arduous the work is.

"Tired from" suggests that the work has been exhausting and their body or mind has become tired as a result of doing it, but that doesn't mean that they no longer enjoy the work.

Consider the example of chopping wood. Some people (myself included) enjoy a bit of good, hard physical labour that gets the blood flowing and builds the muscles. (Especially if you're in a white collar role and get to do it infrequently.) If I haven't done it for a while and am out of condition I find that I get tired FROM doing it much earlier than I would get tired OF doing it.

In other words "tired of" is more a question of attitude, "tired from" more a question of exertion.

Comment: If you're *tired from* chopping wood, you take a nap.  If you're *tired of* chopping wood, you get a chainsaw.

Comment: @cjm: But where's the fun in that?? {Remembers the last time I used my chainsaw...} Ah, good point. (Though chainsaws do tend to be a rather blunt instrument for the production of kindling, if one may use the word "blunt" in the most counter-intuitive and metaphorical fashion imaginable.)

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion,

> He is tired from that work.

denotes **physical activity** and / or a **state of fatigue**.

While

> He is tired of that work

denotes **being fed up** and / or the **desire to stop** the work.

Comment: Physical activity is not necessary, fatigue is the key.

Answer (score 4):

"He is tired **of that** work" means, "He is tired of doing that **type of work**"; e. g., "He is tired of filing paperwork in folders all day, because it seems to him to be tedious and meaningless work."

"He is tired **from that** work" means, "He is tired from the **physical difficulty of doing** that work"; such as, "He is tired from lifting heavy pieces of concrete all day."